# How can I connect my react native app to MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, react-native, expo

I'm creating a mobile app for an existing website and trying to connect to a local instance I have running on a MySQL workbench. I've seen others recommend against the use of MySQL but I'm stuck with it, since that's the current database. I'm using `expo` to run my React Native code. Do I need to use a server, like "MAMP?"

Let me know if there is any more info that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect your app directly to your database.

You will need a server/API that acts as an intermediate between the app and the DB. You can code it in most programming languages and if you know PHP, having MAMP on your system will allow you to build your API with PHP.

> I've seen others recommend against the use of mySQL

You should definitely question their reasoning. I've been using MySQL for many years now in small and big projects and it has never been an issue. If they're comparing it to non-relational DBs like Mongo, I can understand, it's easier to setup and maintain a NoSQL database than a relational one.

I assume you're not that experienced but I still purposefully used some terms that may be new to a beginner. Since I don't know your skills, I will refrain from pointing you to specific tutorials/articles.

I recommend you to Google anything you don't understand from this answer.